# Anyone know why compiz isn't working?

Tags: compiz

So the other day I was able to use Compiz just fine now its not showing up in the dash app search> So I removed it reinstalled it still it's a no show... I'm using ubuntu version 12.10 and I need help Thanx in advance... Ok so I tried to run it from the terminal and got this..

```
bill@Computer:~$ compiz
compiz (core) - Info: Loading plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Starting plugin: core
compiz (core) - Error: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try  
using       the --replace option to replace the current window manager.

compiz (core) - Info: Stopping plugin: core
compiz (core) - Info: Unloading plugin: core
bill@Computer:~$
```

Comment: Try running it from the command line. Open a terminal and type <code>compiz</code> Please edit your question to include any error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to activate compiz, you shouldn't run `compiz` command, because it functions as a window manager. To activate compiz, first make sure you have installed it properly by:

```
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Then activate it by typing:

```
compiz --replace
```

...You may want to add that command to your startup applications if it worked. Please comment if you found any problems.

**PS.** you can also see my point in the output log after runnin `compiz` alone, without parameters: `Error: Screen 0 on display ":0" already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.` Which gives you a hint of what to do. :)